# JavaFX Resizing VBOX dynamically

Tags: layout, javafx, resize, vbox, dynamic-resizing

I am having some problems with my VBOX, I looked for other questions that could help me, but sadly nothing worked. I have a VBox with a bunch of slider and buttons, and what happens is that I can rezise it pretty much as I want. So I can make it so small that the buttons inside it will disappear, or I can make it so big that it will cover other parts of my program. I tried vbox.setMaxSize and vbox.setMinxSize, but nothing happed. Should I also do something about the buttons and sliders inside it? I though since the buttons and sliders were Vbox childrem, the changes I made on Vbox would could for them also. I will post the controller class followed by the FXML file, fell free to tell me if other classes are needed. Thank you very much.

### Controller

```
package fotofinish;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

//TODO: Find a better way to have image be refreshed
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(fotofinish.FXMLDocumentController.class.getName());

    Stage stage;
    private FotoFinishModel model = new FotoFinishModel();
    @FXML
    private Slider brightnessSlider;
    @FXML
    private Slider contrastSlider;
    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup brushTypeRadioGroup;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton brushTypeCircleRadioButton;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton brushTypeSpraypaintRadioButton;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton brushTypeSquareRadioButton;
    @FXML
    private ColorPicker brushColorPicker;
    @FXML
    private NumberFieldFX brushSizeNumberField;
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageViewer;
    @FXML
    private ScrollPane imageScrollPane;
    @FXML
    private VBox vbox; 

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        //TODO: WHAT IS BLOCK INCREMENT?
        this.brightnessSlider.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
            if(model.changeBrightness(newValue.doubleValue())) {
                this.refreshImageViewer();
            }
        });

        //TODO: convert to dragged call
        this.contrastSlider.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
            if (model.changeContrast(newValue.doubleValue())) {
                this.refreshImageViewer();
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    private void filterGrayscale(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.applyGrayscaleFilter();
        this.refreshImageViewer();
        this.resetSliders();
    }

    @FXML
    private void filterSepia(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.applySepiaFilter();
        this.refreshImageViewer();
        this.resetSliders();
    }

    @FXML
    private void filterInstant(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.applyInstantFilter();
        this.refreshImageViewer();
        this.resetSliders();
    }

    @FXML
    private void filterCustom(ActionEvent ignored) {
        //TODO: code to create custom filter popup and get arguments for custom filter
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "TODO: custom filter popup launched");
        model.applyCustomFilter();
        this.refreshImageViewer();
        this.resetSliders();
    }

    @FXML
    private void filterNone(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.resetImageToOriginal();
        this.refreshImageViewer();
        this.resetSliders();
    }

    @FXML
    private void brushTypeCircle(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.setBrushTypeCircle();
    }

    @FXML
    private void brushTypeSquare(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.setBrushTypeSquare();
    }

    @FXML
    private void brushTypeSpraypaint(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.setBrushTypeSpraypaint();
    }

    @FXML
    private void helpDoc(ActionEvent ignored) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "TODO: help document launched");
    }

    @FXML
    private void aboutDialog(ActionEvent ignored) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "TODO: about dialog created");
    }

    @FXML
    private void brushColor(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.changeBrushColor(this.brushColorPicker.getValue());
    }

    @FXML
    private void brushSize(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.changeBrushSize(Integer.parseInt(this.brushSizeNumberField.getText()));
    }

    //TODO: make title setting more intelligent
    @FXML
    private void open(ActionEvent ignored) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "open file chooser launched");
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Open Image");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png")); //TODO: add other types
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null); //TODO: needs value in order to block main window
        if (selectedFile != null) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "file {0} choosen in open file chooser", selectedFile);
            model.loadImage(selectedFile);
            this.refreshImageViewer();
            this.stage.setTitle("Foto Finish - " + selectedFile);
        } else {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "no file selected in open file chooser");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void galleryButterfly(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.loadGalleryButterflyImage();
        this.refreshImageViewer();
    }

    @FXML
    private void galleryTeddyBear(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.loadGalleryTeddyBearImage();
        this.refreshImageViewer();
    }

    @FXML
    private void galleryPrincess(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.loadGalleryPrincessImage();
        this.refreshImageViewer();
    }

    @FXML
    private void galleryFirefighter(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.loadGalleryFirefighterImage();
        this.refreshImageViewer();
    }

    @FXML
    private void save(ActionEvent ignored) {
        model.saveImage();
    }

    @FXML
    private void saveAs(ActionEvent ignored) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "save as file chooser launched");
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Save Image");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png")); //TODO: add other types
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null); //TODO: needs value in order to block main window
        if (selectedFile != null) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "file {0} choosen in save as file chooser", selectedFile);
            model.saveImageAs(selectedFile);
        } else {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "no file selected in save as file chooser");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void quit(ActionEvent ignored) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "quitting");
        Platform.exit(); //TODO: make this detect unsaved changes
    }

    @FXML
    private void newFile(ActionEvent ignored) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "TODO: new file created");
    }

    private void refreshImageViewer() {
        this.imageViewer.setImage(model.getImage());
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "image refreshed");
    }

    //TODO: make this connect better with FXML default value
    private void resetSliders() {
        this.brightnessSlider.setValue(0);
        this.contrastSlider.setValue(0);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "brightness and contrast sliders reset");
    }

    public void setStage(Stage stageFromMain) {
        this.stage = stageFromMain;
    }
}
```

### FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.input.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="500.0" minWidth="600.0" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fotofinish.FXMLDocumentController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="1034.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileNew" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#newFile" text="New">
                     <accelerator>
                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="N" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                     </accelerator>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileOpen" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#open" text="Open">
                     <accelerator>
                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="O" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                     </accelerator>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open from Gallery">
                    <items>
                      <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileGalleryButterfly" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#galleryButterfly" text="Butterfly" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileGalleryTeddyBear" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#galleryTeddyBear" text="Teddy Bear" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileGalleryPrincess" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#galleryPrincess" text="Princess" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileGalleryFirefighter" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#galleryFirefighter" text="Firefighter" />
                    </items>
                  </Menu>
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileSave" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#save" text="Save">
                     <accelerator>
                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="S" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                     </accelerator>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileSaveAs" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveAs" text="Save As">
                     <accelerator>
                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="S" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="DOWN" shortcut="UP" />
                     </accelerator>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="menubarFileQuit" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#quit" text="Quit">
                     <accelerator>
                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="C" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                     </accelerator></MenuItem>
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem fx:id="menubarHelpFotoFinishHelpMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#helpDoc" text="Foto Finish Help">
                     <accelerator>
                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="F1" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                     </accelerator></MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="menubarHelpAboutMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#aboutDialog" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.14941569282136896" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <VBox fx:id="vbox" alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="-11.0" layoutY="25.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="100.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label fx:id="sliderLabel" alignment="TOP_LEFT" text="Sliders">
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <GridPane alignment="CENTER">
                          <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="104.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="84.0" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                           <children>
                              <Button fx:id="filterGrayscaleButton" contentDisplay="TOP" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#filterGrayscale" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="84.0" text="Grayscale" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                 <opaqueInsets>
                                    <Insets top="50.0" />
                                 </opaqueInsets>
                              </Button>
                              <Button fx:id="filterSepiaButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#filterSepia" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="83.0" text="Sepia" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <Button fx:id="filterInstantButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#filterInstant" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="83.0" text="Instant" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                              <Button fx:id="filterCustomButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#filterCustom" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Custom" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                              <Button fx:id="filterNoneButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#filterNone" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="None" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                           </children>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </GridPane>
                        <GridPane prefHeight="271.0" prefWidth="176.0">
                          <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="88.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="290.0" minHeight="26.0" prefHeight="59.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="233.0" minHeight="6.0" prefHeight="40.0" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="127.0" minHeight="28.0" prefHeight="56.0" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="148.0" minHeight="23.0" prefHeight="34.0" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="124.0" minHeight="41.0" prefHeight="51.0" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                           <children>
                              <Label fx:id="brightnessLabel" text="Brightness" />
                              <Label fx:id="contrastLabel" text="Contrast" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <Slider fx:id="brightnessSlider" max="1.0" min="-1.0" minorTickCount="10" orientation="HORIZONTAL" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <Slider fx:id="contrastSlider" max="1.0" min="-1.0" minorTickCount="10" orientation="HORIZONTAL" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                              <Label text="Saturation" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                              <Slider max="1.0" min="-1.0" minorTickCount="10" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                           </children>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </GridPane>
                        <Label fx:id="drawingLabel" text="Drawing" />
                        <ColorPicker fx:id="brushColorPicker" onAction="#brushColor" />
                        <Label fx:id="brushTypeLabel" text="Brush Type" />
                        <RadioButton fx:id="brushTypeCircleRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#brushTypeCircle" selected="true" text="Circle">
                           <toggleGroup>
                              <ToggleGroup fx:id="brushTypeRadioGroup" />
                           </toggleGroup>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton fx:id="brushTypeSquareRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#brushTypeSquare" text="Square" toggleGroup="$brushTypeRadioGroup" />
                        <RadioButton fx:id="brushTypeSpraypaintRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#brushTypeSpraypaint" text="Spraypaint" toggleGroup="$brushTypeRadioGroup" />
                        <Label fx:id="brushSizeLabel" text="Brush Size" />
                        <fotofinish.NumberFieldFX fx:id="brushSizeTextField" onAction="#brushSize" text="10" />
                        <Label fx:id="filtersLabel" text="Filters" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="369.0" prefWidth="465.0">
               <children>
                  <ScrollPane layoutX="145.0" layoutY="111.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <content>
                        <ImageView fx:id="imageViewer" fitHeight="577.0" fitWidth="1010.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
                     </content>
                  </ScrollPane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: What is the exact issue and desired behavior?  What are you asking somebody to help you solve?  How would they know that it is solved and that everything is working as expected?  You have not marked any of the answers to any of your previous questions correct, were they all insufficient in some way?

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Do you want the left side of the SplitPane to have a minimum width?

Comment: Sorry about not having marking them correctly, they did help me, Im new at stack so I did not know it was important to mark them as correctly. Yes Itachi, I though it was the VBox but it is actually the splitPaneAt the momment I pretty much want to know how I can limit the size of the SplitPane and its componets. Right now I can strech them as much as I want, and also I can make the SplitPane so small that I wont even be able to see the componets inside it, such as buttons and sliders. so I want a maximum and minimum size.